# How to create a jQuery function (beginner)

Tags: jquery, function, syntax, parameters

I am just starting with jQuery, and am trying to make a function. I would appreciate help with syntax.

http://jsfiddle.net/e2s8besv/

```
<p>blink me<p>

<style>p {display:none;}</style>

<script>
    (function( $ ) {
        $.fn.blink= function(speed) {
            var speed = $(speed).val();
            $(this).fadeIn(speed).fadeOut(speed).blink(speed);
        };
    }( jQuery));

    $("p").blink(1500);
</script>
```

Comment: There's a `<blink>` tag for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `val()` there:

```
$.fn.blink= function(speed) {
    $(this).fadeIn(speed).fadeOut(speed).blink(speed);
};
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e2s8besv/1/)

But I would suggest to `return` jQuery instance also. So you will be able to reach this element in future or work with elements collection, not first matched element only:

```
$.fn.blink= function(speed) {
    return this.each( function() {
        $(this).fadeIn(speed).fadeOut(speed).blink(speed);
    });
};
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e2s8besv/2/)